# Is it possible to preset an online image in a HTML file input?

Tags: html, forms, image

I've got a page where you can chainge an image, but I can't find any way to preset the current one (that is currently being hosted on the site).

I was thinking it could work like this:

```
<input type='file' value='thesite.com/image.jpg'>
```

But it doesn't show that any file is or could be selected. Is it even possible?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider trying to change your avatar on any site you belong to. Typically, the current image is shown (as an img) and a button is given to change the current image. The button brings up a file-picker. If a new image is chosen, the preview image is changed. A file-picker is for local-files only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way is to create a `img` tag nearby like answered there:

[Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Comment: So the solution is: Only show a preview, with an option to chainge it. If another is set, chainge the preview-image to it. To check if a new image was selected is to check if the post request doesn't chainge is to check for the image part, or the input with a file that doesn't have a name, right?